# django template inbuilt tag search

Tags: python, django

I want to check wether my django template has an `extends block` or not.

Is there an `inbuilt function` in `django` that can tell whether the `template` contains a particular `tag` or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this

`[isinstance(node, ExtendsNode) for node in template.nodelist]`